# Views XML Backend, Render URL as MP3 player

Tags: views

I have a podcast feed that currently i am manually maintaining. I am planning to automate the xml generation in the near future from one site then have it displaying on another.

I am trying to get the displaying part to work now. I am using Views XML Backend to pull the feed (I don't want to import the content as nodes as there is no need to) which is working for me on the text stuff.

I have an enclosure tag and a guid tag in the xml that has the URL to the MP3 file. I want the url to change from being a link (which I had to use the rewrite to link feature in views) to an Embedded MP3 player that displays in a page or block.

Anyone got any tips or suggestions on how to do that? I've tried a few things and am yet to find anything that works.

Running Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Guess you should have every mp3 path wrapped by a player instance somehow. [jPlayer](https://www.drupal.org/project/jplayer) has a nice field formatter which maybe works with your Views setup. Otherwise you'll maybe have to try to accomplish this on template level.